# Delay in TCP communication

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have 2 c++ applications communicating over tcp/ip. One application acts as a client and another one acts as a server. We have observed some delay in receiving data into client. This delay keeps on increasing during a day from few seconds to few minutes in a day.

How we concluded that delay is in communication ?
We have debug statement that prints timestamp when data in ready for write in server. Also we have debug statements in client when we receive that data. After comparing those timestamp we realized that we received data in client after few minutes it was written by server. Each data ha id so it's easy for us to know it's same data whose timestamp is recorded at server & client.

Send/Receive buffer sizes from netstat command : -
We have 1GB send buffer in server which is filled max upto 300MB when this delay is seen.
We have 512MB receive buffer in client which always shows 0 whenever delay is seen. That indicates client is processing data fast enough to make sure that sender(server) will not slow down.

It's my assumption that somehow data is accumulated in send buffer of server that is causing this delay?

Is my assumption correct? Is there solution for this?

Update 1 :- One important fact that I forgot to mention that **both the apps are running on same machine**. They are suppose to run different machine that's why they use tcp but in current situation they are running on same machine so **there should not be a problem of bandwidth**.

Comment: That sounds strange. I mean, of course there is bound to be some delay between 'sending' and 'receiving', but not in this magnitude. However it would be great, if you could share an [mre] with us. Maybe we can spot the problem then.

Comment: The assumptions might be correct or they might be not. There is very few known about the application and there are only selected data presented. It is not even clear how often messages are sent, how large they are and if these information combined with the observed size of the send buffer could explain the delay. Solutions cannot be proposed before properly understanding the problem first, i.e. why messages might be stuck in the send buffer. Might be an issue of the connection, of the server, .. whatever

Comment: I think the fact that the client buffer is empty points into a direction where the server is waiting for an acknowledge by the client that it has actually received a packet. Have you decoupled packet handling in the client? Or do you immediately process packets in the receive handler? As said there basically isn't enough info to make an analysis

Comment: (1) what is the network interface speed: is it plausible that sending 300Mb of data over this interface takes a few minutes? (2) if it is possible try to have TCP timestamps enabled and figure out the delay TCP sees (or get RTT estimation by some other means), because then we can pinpoint the location of the buffer. (3) what is advertized receiver window (you should be able to see it in wireshark). if the receiver advertizes 0, the sender can't send anything.

Comment: @all : I will try to get more info and minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @PepijnKramer : How does it matter if I am processing packets in receive handler or not to ack sent by client. As far as I know sending ack is done by tcp layer and has nothing to do with user process packet handling.

Comment: Is it possible the clocks on the two machines are drifting apart over the course of the day and that is misleading you?

Comment: Just thinking out loud, to not discount an issue at the client side.

Comment: Is the "sending timestamp" only when the data is ready for sending, not when it is actually sent?

Comment: @molbdnilo : Log statement is just before I write to socket so I think it is safe to assume that timestamp is when we send it.

Comment: Try also monitoring the memory usage of sender and receiver - a gradual slowing down is very often related to memory being leaked and processes using up all available RAM.

Comment: "just before I write to socket" is not the same as "when the data is sent". Also, what is your network topology? there can be a delay somewhere between two hosts.

Comment: can you get tcp_probe data? I can't find any better doc than [this](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/tcpprobe) and reading [code](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.c#L52). What is needed is cwnd and srtt. Srtt should be the last number in the entry. Cwnd is in the example in the doc.

Comment: actually, root cause of the delay is that someone is producing data that needs to be sent faster then this data can actually be send (limited by bandwidth). this delay can accumulate at the sender (if the application is producing data much faster then the speed of network interface), or because somewhere on the path there is an interface with mush smaller bandwidth then the sending interface.

Comment: @Effie : I updated my description to reflect the fact that both client & server are running on same machine so bandwidth should not be a problem?

Comment: damn, this is weird. but maybe you could try actually sending packets over the network. maybe "loopback" interface is not optimized and doing something strange.