# TCP Sender Buffer Queue Pileup,even though Reciever Buffer Queue is 0

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

For a tcp connection between a server/sender and client/reciever, we are currently facing a send buffer queue pile up, this specifically happens on heavy loads, else the receiver works fine. Even though sender Queue size keeps increasing even though reciever's recieve TCP Buffer Queue stays at 0,that is reciever keeps reading but the data is delayed,on an additional note we are using non blocking tcp sockets.
the Queue Sizes are obtained from netstat -nap command.

Earlier as the TCP buffer was being completely filled,we had tried increasing the TCP buffer size using setsockopt ,the issue of completely filling the buffer was resolved yet the delay is still present.

any suggestions that might get me closer to resolution,would be appreciated
thanks.

Edit:Recently Discovered we are using TCP_NODELAY setsockopt on the sender.

i will try to create a minimum viable example.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70359213/delay-in-tcp-communication

Comment: generally i can envision two situations where sender buffer should be full; (1) your application feeds sender socket data faster than the network interface can send it out. In this case there is no place for the data to go but to stay in the sender buffer [in theory it can stay anywhere in the sender system, but in Linux tcp_small_queues should prevent it from being somewhere else, although i am not entirely sure]. (2) it will also probably feel much more after a packet loss during loss recovery. However in this case receiver queue should be non-empty too.

Comment: generally, if you want small delay you should reduce the size of the sender buffer, not increase it. however in this case you will probably have the pile the data in your application when it tries to feed data into the socket. without knowing the characteristics of data being send, i have no other ideas.

Comment: This situation (where the outgoing data backs up on the TCP-sender's side for longer than expected) is typically caused by one or more TCP packets getting dropped, such that the TCP stack has to stop and resend the lost packets before it can continue.  (You can artificially induce that behavior simply by unplugging either the server or the client's Ethernet cable for a second or two during the transmission, then plugging it back in)

Comment: You can't really avoid the occasional backup (unless your network hardware and receiving clients never have any errors, ha ha), but you can manage it gracefully; e.g. by only generating more bytes-to-send when the TCP socket select()'s as ready-for-write and you have no more already-generated-bytes (from last time) left to send out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.